# How to build table as in Settings app with storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

We want to build table like in native settings application. There should be sections of static  cells and one section of dynamic cells.

Is there ways to do it just with storyboards without .xib files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it nicely with a UITableViewController subclass and some static cells in the table view. More or less all you do is drop some cells into the table view and wire them up to  the outlets in your controller. [Here is](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_an_Xcode_Storyboard_to_Create_a_Static_Table_View) a good guide.

Comment: Thx. It's clear but in this example all of your cells is static. In your example my problem is the following:
I need to show Make and Model in first section and i have to show some amount of photos in second section. One photo per one cell.